# How do I expose my service to the world?

Tags: vagrant, kubernetes

Instead of working with google cloud, I decided to set up Kuberenetes on my own machine. I made a docker image of my hello-world web server. I set up hello-controller.yaml:

```yaml
apiversion: v1
kind: ReplicationController
metadata:
    name: hello
    labels:
        name: hello
spec:
    replicas: 1
    selector:
        name: hello
    template:
        metadata:
            labels:
                name: hello
        spec:
            containers:
            - name: hello
              image: flaggy/hello
              ports:
              - containerPort: 8888
```

Now I want to expose the service to the world. I don't think vagrant provider has a load balancer (which seems to be the best way to do it). So I tried with NodePort service type. However, the newly created NodePort does not seem to be listened on any IP I try. Here's hello-service.yaml:

```yaml
apiversion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
    name: hello
    labels:
        name: hello
spec:
    type: NodePort
    selector:
        name: hello
    ports:
    - port: 8888
```

If I log into my minion I can access port 8888

```
$ curl 10.246.1.3:8888
Hello!
```

When I describe my service this is what I get:

```
$ kubectl.sh describe service/hello
W0628 15:20:45.049822    1245 request.go:302] field selector: v1 - events - involvedObject.name - hello: need to check if this is versioned correctly.
W0628 15:20:45.049874    1245 request.go:302] field selector: v1 - events - involvedObject.namespace - default: need to check if this is versioned correctly.
W0628 15:20:45.049882    1245 request.go:302] field selector: v1 - events - involvedObject.kind - Service: need to check if this is versioned correctly.
W0628 15:20:45.049887    1245 request.go:302] field selector: v1 - events - involvedObject.uid - 2c0005e7-1dc2-11e5-8369-0800279dd272: need to check if this is versioned correctly.
Name:           hello
Labels:         name=hello
Selector:       name=hello
Type:           NodePort
IP:         10.247.5.87
Port:           <unnamed>   8888/TCP
NodePort:       <unnamed>   31423/TCP
Endpoints:      10.246.1.3:8888
Session Affinity:   None
No events.
```

I cannot find anyone listening on port 31423 which, as I gather, should be the external port for my service. I am also puzzled about IP 10.247.5.87.

I note this

```
$ kubectl.sh get nodes
NAME         LABELS                              STATUS
10.245.1.3   kubernetes.io/hostname=10.245.1.3   Ready
```

Why is that IP different from what I see on describe for the service? I tried accessing both IPs on my host:

```
$ curl 10.245.1.3:31423
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 10.245.1.3 port 31423: Connection refused
$ curl 10.247.5.87:31423
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 10.247.5.87 port 31423: No route to host
$
```

So IP 10.245.1.3 is accessible, although port 31423 is not binded to it. I tried routing 10.247.5.87 to vboxnet1, but it didn't change anything:

```
$ sudo route add -net 10.247.5.87 netmask 255.255.255.255 vboxnet1
$ curl 10.247.5.87:31423
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 10.247.5.87 port 31423: No route to host
```

If I do `sudo netstat -anp | grep 31423` on the minion nothing comes up. Strangely, nothing comes up if I do `sudo netstat -anp | grep 8888` either.
There must be either some iptables magic or some interface in promiscuous mode being abused.

Would it be this difficult to get things working on bare metal as well? I haven't tried AWS provider either, but I am getting worried.

Comment: 10.247.5.87 is the IP address for your service *inside* the cluster. It won't work outside of the cluster.

Your `$ curl 10.245.1.3:31423` really ought to have worked. I've asked another team member to comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things.

Your single pod is 10.246.1.3:8888 - that seems to work.

Your service is 10.247.5.87:8888 - that should work as long as you are within your cluster (it's virtual - you will not see it in `netstat`).  This is the first thing to verify.

Your node is 10.245.1.3 and your service should ALSO be on 10.245.1.3:31423 - this is the part that does not seem to be working correctly.  Like service IPs, this binding is virtual - it should show up in `iptables-save` but not `netstat`.  If you log into your node (minion), can you `curl localhost:31423` ?

You might find this doc useful: https://github.com/thockin/kubernetes/blob/docs-debug-svcs/docs/debugging-services.md